mpirun takes 3 minutes to start on a cluster node... -- how can I get more information?
Problem: mpi programs take very long time (a few minutes) to start
System:  ubuntu server 20.04 Linux kernel: 5.15.0-107-generic
Toolchain: gcc: 11.4.0 openmpi/openrte: 4.1.2 CUDA: 12.4 nvidia driver: 550.54
Hello All, recently I encountered a bizarre thing that all my parallel MPI programs take very long time to launch on one of my cluster nodes, after I added two GPU cards to the node (now it has 8 cards) and restarted. It turns out even a dry-run of mpirun command on that single node would take some 3 minutes to launch... e.g.:
hiroshi@node16:~$ time mpirun
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun could not find anything to do.

It is possible that you forgot to specify how many processes to run
via the "-np" argument.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

real    2m58.576s
user    0m0.041s
sys     2m57.982s

However, the MPI programs themselves seem to be running without any further errors (albeit very slow). On the other hands, the non-MPI programs don't have this symptom, and yes, the MPI jobs on the other nodes seem to be running without any delay. Using -v with mpirun doesn't seem to give more information, either. For example, with the "stream" bandwidth tool I get:
hiroshi@node16:~/src/streams$ time mpirun -np 2 -v stream_c 
-------------------------------------------------------------
STREAM version $Revision: 1.8 $
-------------------------------------------------------------
This system uses 8 bytes per array element.
-------------------------------------------------------------
Total Aggregate Array size = 10000000 (elements)
Total Aggregate Memory per array = 76.3 MiB (= 0.1 GiB).
Total Aggregate memory required = 228.9 MiB (= 0.2 GiB).
Data is distributed across 2 MPI ranks
   Array size per MPI rank = 5000000 (elements)
   Memory per array per MPI rank = 38.1 MiB (= 0.0 GiB).
   Total memory per MPI rank = 114.4 MiB (= 0.1 GiB).
-------------------------------------------------------------
Each kernel will be executed 10 times.
 The *best* time for each kernel (excluding the first iteration)
 will be used to compute the reported bandwidth.
The SCALAR value used for this run is 0.420000
-------------------------------------------------------------
Your timer granularity/precision appears to be 1 microseconds.
Each test below will take on the order of 6638 microseconds.
   (= 6638 timer ticks)
Increase the size of the arrays if this shows that
you are not getting at least 20 timer ticks per test.
-------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING -- The above is only a rough guideline.
For best results, please be sure you know the
precision of your system timer.
-------------------------------------------------------------
Function    Best Rate MB/s  Avg time     Min time     Max time
Copy:          37610.1     0.004883     0.004254     0.007186
Scale:         18426.9     0.009645     0.008683     0.012610
Add:           20624.9     0.012883     0.011636     0.015395
Triad:         20592.3     0.013218     0.011655     0.016958
-------------------------------------------------------------
Solution Validates: avg error less than 1.000000e-13 on all three arrays
-------------------------------------------------------------

real    2m59.213s
user    0m0.917s
sys     2m59.258s

Note that the stream program finishes correctly with the expected output, although the bandwidth value seems quite low - that's because my users are still running jobs on this node and taking up the memory bandwidth (they won't notice the problem as their job usually take hours to days to finish).
The machine with the problem is the last (node16) of a 16-node cluster configured with slurm and openmpi  mainly for of HPC tasks. It has been working for "production" for about 1 year - so yes, the MPI works quite well before, until I added the last two GPU cards, that is. I don't think it's the cards that caused the problem, though.
So the key point is probably "how did I mess up" - However, apart from plugging in extra GPU cards and re-configuring the GRES setup in slurm, the only thing I changed is probably the PAM configuration for sshd to temporally allow myself to login onto the system (I did add some constraint that forbid the users without any running slurm tasks to login onto computation nodes). not sure why and how I messed up the system/mpi.
Another (hopefully) useful hint, is that nvidia-smi also takes very long time to launch. I don't think it's an MPI program, but I think it needs the information of the currently running parallel programs through OPENRTE.
Please let me know (or point me to the right link) how can I pinpoint the problem... I really don't have a clue on this... Thanks a lot in advance.
Hiroshi
